# Does points are closed in L-spaces

Tags: general-topology

Does one point $x\in X$ is closed where $X$ is an $L$-spaces, 
which is called also Limit-spaces and introduced for the first time by Fréchet.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sequential convergence spaces with the two usual axioms (constant sequences converge to their constant, and any subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit):

Define $X = \{0,1\}$ and every sequence converges to $0$ and every sequences also converges to $1$. You can check pretty easily that this obeys the above axioms.

Then by definition the closed sets in this convergence space are exactly those sets that are closed under sequential limits. So if $A \neq \emptyset$ is closed, we have $p \in \{0,1\}, p \in A$, and the sequence $p,p,p,p,\ldots$ converges to both $0$ and $1$ and so $0,1 \in A$, so the only closed sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$, i.e. $X$ is indiscrete. So points need not be closed.

As slightly more interesting example (which is $T_0$) can be made using the Sierpinski two-point space, which I leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is comment rather than an answer. I am posting it as an answer for two reasons: 1) Better formatting. 2) Easier for the OP to copy the source.

I found the following axioms in Engelking's book:

> **1.7.18** (Frechet [1906] and [1918], Urysohn [1926a]). An $\mathcal L^*$-space is a pair $(X, \lambda)$, where $X$ is a set and $\lambda$ a function (called the limit operator) assigning to some sequences of points of $X$ an element of $X$ (called the limit of the sequence) in such a way that the following conditions are satisfied (we write $\lambda x_i$ instead of $\lambda(\{x_i\})$ and say that $\{x_i\}$ converges to $x$ if $\lambda x_i=x$):
>   (L1) If $x_i=i$ for $i = 1,2,\dots,$ then $\lambda x_i=x$.
>   (L2) If $\lambda x_i=x$, then $\lambda x_{k_i}=x$ for every subsequence $\{x_{k_i}\}$ of $\{x_i\}$.
>   (L3) If a sequence $\{x_i\}$ does not converge to $x$, then it contains a subsequence $\{x_{k_i}\}$ such that no subsequence of $\{x_{k_i}\}$ converges to $x$.
>   An $\mathcal L^*$ space is called $\mathcal S^*$-space if it fulfills also
>   (L4) If $\lambda x_i=x$ and $\lambda x^i_j=x_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots$, then there exist sequences of positive integers $i_1,i_2,\dots$ and $j_1,j_2,\dots$ such that $\lambda x^{i_k}_{j_k}=x$.

If some of these axioms are what you mean by L-space, you should copy them to your post and give precise definition of what you mean. (So that your post is not as unclear as in the current state.)

If you want copy part of the text from this post, simply click on "edit" or click on "source" in the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1814710/revisions).

Comment: The L3 axiom makes it what is now known as a topological convergence space. L4 makes it sequential, or Fréchet-Urysohn, IIRC, I forgot which.